# Using visjs manipulation to create workflow dependencies

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

We are currently using visjs version 3 to map the dependencies of our custom built workflow engine.  This has been WONDERFUL because it helps us to visualize the flow and find invalid or missing dependencies.  What we want to do next is simplify the process of building the dependencies using the visjs manipulation feature.  The idea would be that we would display a large group of nodes and allow the user to order them correctly.  We then want to be able to submit that json structure back to the server for processing.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Vis.js dispatches various [events](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) that relate to user interactions with graph (e.g. manipulations, or position changes) for which you can add handlers that modify or store the data on change. If you use [DataSets](http://visjs.org/docs/data/) to store nodes and edges in your network, you can always use the DataSets' `get()` function to retrieve all elements in you handler in JSON format. Then in your handler, just use an ajax request to transmit the JSON to your server to store the entire graph in your DB or by saving the JSON as a file.

The oppposite for loading the graph: simply query the JSON from your server and inject it into the node and edge DataSets' using the `set` method.

You can also store the networks current options using the network's `getOptions` method, which returns all applied options as json.